# Where can I train my Pokemon in HeartGold/SoulSilver after Kanto?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I have been using the Elite Four to train my Pokemon while running through Kanto.  Unfortunately, I made the mistake of defeating Blue in Viridian City without leveling up my Pokemon enough, so now the upgraded version of the Elite Four is very difficult (All their Pokemon are lvl 60-70).  Where is a good place to train in order to quickly level up my Pokemon, which are around the mid to low 50s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a Sinnoh game from the 4th generation, the best method is actually to trade them to that game and train them up on the wild pokemon in the Battle Zone (the island containing the battle frontier), especially Route 227 and Stark Mountain.

The highest level wild Pokemon in the Johto remakes are the level 45-50 Pokemon in Mt. Silver and the lowest floor or Cerulean Cave.

If you don't have any Sinnoh games, your best option is to keep doing rematches with trainers, which can be found by the exclamation marks next to route names on your Pokegear map (some of those trainers just want to give you items, but most are rematches). or just keep attempting the Elite Four, even if you don't succeed (though this may drastically lower your Pokemon's happiness because of the repeated fainting).

Another option is to do Gym Leader rematches in the Fighting Dojo in Saffron City, but this is slow because you can only fight certain Gym Leaders each day, and you need to collect their phone numbers beforehand. A guide to getting the Gym Leader's phone numbers is available on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9gear#Gym_Leader_phone_listing).After you get their phone number, call them at the correct time, and they will show up in the Fighting Dojo.

Their Pokemon are levelled up significantly. Most of the Gym leaders are in the 50-60 range, but some (Blue) go up to level 70.

Comment: By "battle area", if you mean the battle tower/factory/castle etc. then you don't gain experience there at all.  If you mean something else, perhaps you should make it clearer.  The rest of this answer is very useful.

Comment: @StrixVaria: The island the Battle Frontier is on is called the Battle Area. It contains high levelled wild pokemon.

Comment: Actually, my bad, it's called the "Battle Zone"

Comment: To the person who proposed an edit: The levels are about the rematches. When you fight Blue the second time for a rematch, his Pidgeot is level 72, not level 60.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to battle wild Pokemon in Mt. Silver. You'll encounter Pokemon from levels 40 - 50 there.

Another option is re-battling Gym Leaders. Serebii has a [page](http://www.serebii.net/heartgoldsoulsilver/gym-rematch.shtml) detailing how to obtain their phone numbers, and what Pokemon they have. I find this the most efficient way because during the timeframe that you can rematch them, you can battle them as many times as you want. Call them, battle them, leave the dojo, and repeat. As you are battling a trainer, you get 1.5x the experience you would obtain from battling a wild Pokemon of the same species + level.

If you don't care about your Pokemon's happiness, and have a Sinnoh game, you can trade them over and fight wild Pokemon there (I would suggest Stark Mountain). Trading over a Pokemon to another game will reset it's happiness, but they will gain 1.5x the experience they would in their native game.

Answer (score 1):

The thing I do is trade over a level 100 from a previous game to the new game, get an exp share and put it on the the Pokemon (or *Pokemons*) you want to level up. Go through the elite four or just battle randomly. That should level up your Pokemon well!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have many tips:

- Use rare candies (search up where to find all of them
- Go to mount silver and you get around 1000 exp per win on the wild pokemon
- Battle the gym leaders again by getting their phone numbers and calling them on the right time
- Battle the elite 4 again
- Go to the day care centre and put pokemon in and go to the gym in ecruteak city and put something heavy on the 'up' button and leave your ds in charge overnight (I preferably tape down the button)
- Battle red at the top of mount silver
- Have a traded pokemon (this allows it to gain more exp from battle)
- Catch several chanseys from the safari zone or the mary and oak swarm and they have a 5% chance of holding an item called lucky egg that gives you 50% more exp from battle
- Teach it powerful moves so it is more powerful therefore wins more battles
- Give it drinks (e.g. carbos) to increase stats therefore winning more battles
  get a high level pokemon in ypur party and the one you want to train at the front and start a battle and switch to the high level pokemon straight away and win

Using these methods, I got my houndour level 15 to a houndoom level 100 in less than a week.

Hope I helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Wild Pokemon in the Mt. Silver area are all levels 40-50. I've trained there for a bit, until ultimately you'll need to re-battle other trainers.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip for fast leveling. As been told already, rebattle the gym leaders. But instead of waiting for the right moment to call 'em, you can just change your Timeset on the DS menu. this allows you to arrange a rematch whenever you want! I did this for a while, I battled with erika over and over to train my lugia and Ninetales! Great way, just call the right gym leader for you kill quick and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Usually late in the game, trainers like School Kid Chad and Youngster Joey have tougher pokemon. Its better to fight them as if they have a level 50 you could get over 1000 XP. Though i have VERY tough pokemon (2 level 100s) and if you have over level 60 you might as well travel. If you think your training is bad, breed pokemon. You can have something crazy like 11 charizards and 65 Croconaws via breeding.

Answer (score 0):

As you have heard, you can level your Pokémon in Mt. Silver. There are Pokémon level 40-50. After that, if you don't care about your Pokémon's happiness, you can deposit all your money to your mom and challenge the elite four. For each Pokémon defeated you usually gain over 3000+ exp.

Answer (score 0):

I train at route 47 and get them to 40-50 and then take on the E4. the place is the grass next to the waterfall. get there by surf.

Answer (score 0):

Put 2 pokemom in the day care at a time then go to Ecruteak gym and then get a heavy object put it on the up button and do it when you go to sleep then when you wake up check your game then go back to the day care you should see your pokemon gained levels
Hopefully this helped coz it helped for me

Answer (score -1):

Go to Mt. Silver. If you haven't beaten the Elite 4 yet, just go to victory road.

If you haven't already caught them: Go to pewter city get the rainbow/silver wing, go to Bell Tower (Soul-Silver) or Whirl Islands (Heart Gold), and kill Ho-Oh/Lugia who are at lvl 70. They will respawn after you defeat the Elite 4

Or use the daycare leave to pokemon there for a week and should be level a hundred also if you leave them in daycare keep your DS on but plugged in.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that daycare centers level up pokemon based on in-game steps taken and not based on real-time. While several games have a location or two where you can hold down a direction and walk infinitely (X/Y's Lumiose city, several areas in various games with the directional arrows that send you flying), simply leaving the DS on for several days won't accomplish much.

Comment: Also, the Ho-Oh/Lugia tip isn't terribly helpful, as the question is asking for help leveling to beat the powered up E4. The legendaries will provide, at best, a one-time XP infusion (good for a level or three), and then they're gone until the E4 (the group that he needs more levels to beat) are beaten.